# SQLite query sequence listing

Tags: android, sqlite

```
private Cursor KayitGetirAramabaslayan(){


        memberName="uterine brother";
        kosullar="";
        String arr[] = memberName.split(" ");
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
            kosullar=kosullar + " or title like '" + arr[i]+"%'" ;
        }

         SQLiteDatabase db = kategoriler.getReadableDatabase();
         Cursor cursor = db.query("nedir", SELECT  ," title like '"+memberName+"%'"+ kosullar+"" , null, null, null,"title ASC" );

         startManagingCursor(cursor);


        return cursor;
         }
```

I'm sorry for my bad english

There is no problematical situation in function.let me tell it according to the example above.when written (questioned) in drop line  "uterine brother", "uterine" or "brother",it will list all of them.I just want to say that the beginnings with "uterine brother" must be initially listed and then the other words must be listed.That is to say;
Priority must be in all of the word. And then it must be listed in the other words.Do you have any idea about how we can do it?

[image]

Comment: i could not understand what you want, can you giveme an example, like what you are searching and a list of results?

Comment: is that what you want?
Cursor cursor = db.query("nedir", SELECT  ,"title like %"+memberName+"%"+ kosullar , null, null, null,"title ASC" );

Comment: @avjr I updated the question.
Sorry for my bad english. I could not find the answer for a long time. I do not tell my troubles